# Measuring how much batteries lasts on another system?

Tags: bash, networking, scripting

I have both a Linux computer and Microsoft Vista laptop. I would like to know how much the batteries last on the laptop from the computer. How can I do a script for that, i.e. how to check on Linux when the power wire is unplugged and when it stops sending pings to Linux? I tried to begin with

```
#!/bin/bash
time (
    while [ true ]; do
        ping -c 1 "$1" > /dev/null || break
        sleep 1
    done
)
```

But now I need to modify the script to read if power wire is plugged.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the Windows operating system.

Comment: But I use Linux to measure the time and it needs a bash script.

Comment: Then why do you want to know how long your batteries last on Vista? Linux does not know :-)

Comment: But I think Linux can somehow measure the time when one unplugs the power wire and the time when it stops sending pings. I think this is more accurate that in a single computer as I can't ever be sure that the last thing the Windows done before shutting down was to write the log. Therefore I need another computer to measure the time. And I think this is the easiest in Linux.

Comment: But finding out "if power wire is plugged" has to be done in Windows.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But I don't know how can I send a command from Linux to Windows that returns Linux if the wire is plugged similar than /sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online.

Comment: Figuring out that command is a Windows thing, and should be asked on [su]. We can probably help with sending the command.

Comment: Not entirely off-topic. Look at my answer. Is just a matter of getting the information through network using `wmi-client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows have an API called [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx). - Windows Management Instrumentation

> Purpose
>
> Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is the infrastructure for
>   management data and operations on Windows-based operating systems. You
>   can write WMI scripts or applications to automate administrative tasks
>   on remote computers but WMI also supplies management data to other
>   parts of the operating system and products, for example System Center
>   Operations Manager, formerly Microsoft Operations Manager (MOM), or
>   Windows Remote Management (WinRM).

It´s a proprietary technology simmilar to SNMP or JMX. Both are largely used on monitoring systems like [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) or [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/).

To retrieve this information through network is just a matter of enabling WMI(you will find more information on Windows related forums) and using a wmi client for linux, like [wmi-client](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/wmi-commands-from-linux/)

Example:

`wmic -U Administrator%mysecret //192.168.20.20 "Select WorkingSetSize from Win32_Process Where CommandLine like '%java.exe%'"`

This command will make a query on 192.168.20.20, using the Administrator account and "mysecret" password, get the array of processes and search for any process with a name that looks like `java.exe`

`win32_battery` is the right class to retrieve information about power supply on your notebok. Examples [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/31/using-windows-powershell-to-determine-if-a-laptop-is-on-battery-power.aspx). It´s just a matter of using the `EstimatedChargeRemaining` variable to get the information you want from [Win32_Battery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394074(v=vs.85).aspx) class, using wmi-client on Linux.

**Edit1:** Win32_Battery didn´t worked on my workstation, maybe because it´s a virtual desktop and have no batteries at all. However, i can make other WMI queries:

```
[root@host ~]# wmic -U nicolas -W DOMAIN  //192.x.x.x "SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
Password for [DOMAIN\nicolas]:
CLASS: Win32_OperatingSystem
Caption
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
```

In this case, i used `-W` to tell the command what is the domain/workgroup it have to use instead of the default `WORKGROUP`.

**Related Stuff:** - Things you should take a look at Windows side.

- How to Enable WMI on Windows XP or Windows 7 - [link](https://www.poweradmin.com/help/enablewmi.aspx)
- How to compile wimc(wmi-client) - [link](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Wmic-linux)
- How to open Windows firewall ports to WMI - [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/84c78946-eb05-4068-877d-489153419d13/how-to-enable-the-wmi-entry-in-the-firewall-configuration-using-gpo-on-win7?forum=winserverGP)